# Using ternary operator in angularjs to set an attribute on an element

Tags: angularjs, ternary-operator

I'm using `angularjs` `1.6` and required to use a specific `css` library that will disable a button if the button is defined like:

```
<button disabled="">
   My button
</button>
```

And will enable the button if defined:

```
<button disabled="">
   My button
</button>
```

I'm trying to enable/disable it based on the latest value from a property in a service within my controller, but the button is always showing as enabled even if `someProperty` is defined or not .. any ideas?

```
<button {{ ctrl.myService.getData().someProperty ? '' : 'disabled=""' }}>
   My button
</button>
```

Comment: Use ng-disabled="someProperty"

Comment: as vivz says <button ng-disabled='ctrl.myService.getData().someProperty'>

Comment: `<button ng-disabled="ctrl.myService.getData().someProperty">My button</button>` does not disable the button .. even if `someProperty` does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
<button ng-disabled="ctrl.myService.getData().someProperty ? 'disabled': '' ">
   My button
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this using `ng-disabled` attribute. SO it's like:

```
<button ng-disabled="ctrl.myService.getData().someProperty ? true : false">
   My button
</button>
```

Let me know if it helps.