# Using ng-disabled button is still disabled even if value in condition changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have a button:

```
<button ng-disabled="ctrl.myService.getData().someProperty ? '' : 'disabled'">
  Click me!
</button>
```

When the application loads `someProperty` does not exist on `ctrl.myService.getData()`. So the button is disabled.

But after a few seconds `someProperty` is set on `ctrl.myService.getData()` but my button is still disabled .. any idea why its not enabling the button based on the new property?

Comment: You have to use boolean operators to trigger ng-disabled. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45349719/using-ternary-operator-in-angularjs-to-set-an-attribute-on-an-element/45349944#45349944

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ternary operator in angularjs to set an attribute on an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45349719/using-ternary-operator-in-angularjs-to-set-an-attribute-on-an-element)

Comment: dont see any difference using `true` or `false`

Comment: It is because the value you have to set in your controller. Probably while check ctrl.myService.getData() might not have resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also be sure to call $scope.apply() at the end of your methods execution so it can apply the changes necessary

Answer (score 1):

it should be like this:

In your controller:

```
     <script>
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

           $scope.is_disabled = ctrl.myService.getData().someProperty;
        });
     </script>
```

In Html:

```
    <button ng-disabled="is_disabled ? false : true">
      Click me!
    </button>
```

Comment: using true or false, the value still doesn't change .. it always remains in the original state i.e disabled